# How to link a jQuery UI sortable element with an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

So, basically, how can I link a jQuery UI sortable element with an array, so that some kind of index is put in the array for each sortable element, and when they are moved, the array is sorted accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider get a list of the index back after the element is moved.

```
var listOfId = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
```

For ref:
http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Comment: Assume you have [element1 , element2, element2] (with index 0,1,2)

Comment: If you show the array this order, 
<li id='0'>element1</li>
<li id='1'>element2</li>
<li id='2'>element3</li>
after you changed the order, such as:
<li id='2'>element3</li>
<li id='0'>element1</li>
<li id='1'>element2</li>
using the above method, you will get [2,0,1] in listOfId.